# Update multiple columns wthout Enum.each Ecto Elixir

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a model as `Entry`. I am trying to update all entries in DB with 6 digit number sequence,

```
Entry
|> where(type: "entry:referral")
|> order_by(asc: :id)
|> Repo.all()
```

the above gives me all entries, and the column which I want to update is `referral_number`, its `string` type.

the very first entry will have `"000001"` and next ones `000002` .. `"000010"` and so on.

Is there any way to not use `Enum.each` to update the data, with an incremental numbers?

this is what I got:

```
Entry
|> where(type: "entry:referral")
|> order_by(asc: :id)
|> Repo.all()
|> Enum.with_index
|> Enum.each(fn {entry, index} ->
  referral_number =
    Integer.to_string(index)
    |> String.pad_leading(6, "0")

  Entry.changeset(entry, %{referral_number: referral_number})
  |> Repo.update()
end)
```

Comment: Just to explore more ideas, what DB are you using?

Comment: PostGreSQL, I just want to see if Multi.run can be useful here.

Comment: I think `Multi` can be used, but would make this slow and use more memory depending on the number of rows to update. Instead, using a "window function" in the DB can be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-window.html) to generate the row numbers and speedup the update of all rows.

Since you can't update in the same query of a window function, you need to use a subquery. I managed to do the process in 3 steps:

1. generate the [rows with numbers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-window.html) based on order
2. add the left pad with PostgreSQL's [lpad](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html)
3. update all the rows with the new values

Here is the code representing the steps:

```
import Ecto.Query
alias MyApp.Repo

ordered_rows_query =
  from e in Entry, select: %{
    id: e.id,
    row_number: row_number() |> over(order_by: [asc: e.id])
  }

rows_with_lpad_query =
  from e in Entry, join: o in subquery(ordered_rows_query), on: e.id == o.id, select: %{
    code: fragment("LPAD(?::text, 6, '0')", o.row_number),
    id: e.id
  }

update_query =
  from e in Entry, join: new_codes in subquery(rows_with_lpad_query),
    on: new_codes.id == e.id,
    update: [set: [code: new_codes.code]]

Repo.update_all(update_query, [])
```

There is a way to collapse the first two queries into one, but it's slightly difficult to read:

```
ordered_rows_with_lpad_query =
  from e in Entry, select: %{
    id: e.id,
    code: fragment("LPAD(?::text, 6, '0')", row_number() |> over(order_by: [asc: e.id]))
  }

update_query =
  from e in Entry, join: new_codes in subquery(ordered_rows_with_lpad_query),
    on: new_codes.id == e.id,
    update: [set: [code: new_codes.code]]

Repo.update_all(update_query, [])
```

See [Ecto.Query.WindowAPI](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.WindowAPI.html) for details on how to use the window functions in Ecto.